# Google Drive mobile offline app

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm developing a mobile app that will have hyperlinks to a user's Google Drive documents.  If the mobile device is offline, will the hyperlinks still function if the mobile device owner has installed the Google Drive Android/iOS app?  i.e. does document URL retrieved online work for offline access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Drive Android/iOS app downloads online files to local storage and serve from the local file system when device got offline. You should follow a similar approach.

Comment: This does not answer my question - does a hyperlink that points to a Google Doc file and which works with an internet connection also work in offline mode?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand what you meant by a hyperlink that works in offline mode. Are you asking will it open similarly to a doc opening in offline mode? The links we're giving out are the same what Drive frontend would link the document to. So, I guess the answer is yes.